# ARIA markup for elements that are tabs on desktop but collapsible on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, tabs, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a series of panels that work with tabs. I'm using `aria-controls`, `aria-selected`, `role="tablist"`, `role="tab"` on the tabs and `aria-labelledby`, `aria-hidden` and `role="tabpanel"` on the panels - all seems good.

However, below a certain screen width I want the same elements to be collapsible, expanded and collapsed by buttons at the top. Obviously I need to hide the tabs list, and include buttons at the top of each panel which are hidden above the breakpoint. I would use `aria-controls` for the buttons - but there seems to be a few overlaps / clashes between the accessibility markup for the two layouts.

Is there a right way of doing this, or is it simply the case that I should ignore accessibility markup for the "mobile" version, assuming it's irrelevant to screen readers? Are there scenarios where the accessibility markup is necessary for responsive layouts?

Comment: This isn't reall a UX question I'm afraid. You've already decided what you want the user experience to be, so now you're at the point of implementing it. And that falls outside the scope of this site I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonW I'd argue that UX designers are the ones to define ARIA labels, and not programmers. Inclusive design modules are far more common in HCID degrees than in computer science. This question is about the user experience of users using AT - that's more UX than programming in my view.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to simply show the tabs as buttons (i.e. change the styling) in the small screen layout but leave the markup exactly the same. If you want to have multiple sections expandable simultaneously, then you can use aria-multiselectable (which essentially turns tabs into accordions).

Do not ignore accessibility for mobile. Mobile is as easy to make accessible as the desktop version and is becoming the primary way that users access many web sites and applications.